Is it possible to create an Outlook add-in for automating multiple out-of-office appointments?
At my organization, when one is taking some time off of work, we traditionally create "OOO appointments" on our and our teammates' calendars. For example, if I want to be out of office for Wed, May 22, 2024 from 8-11am, I would do both of the following:
Create an appointment during that day and time, invite my teammates to it, set the reminder to None, and set the status to "Free." This way, my teammates will see my OOO appointment on their calendar, but it won't show them as "Busy" when they accept it.
Create an appointment during that day and time on my calendar, with the status set to "Out of office." This way, I will be shown in Outlook (and Teams) as OOO.
It's annoying to need to go through this process every time one needs to take time off. I had the idea of creating an Outlook add-in for automating this: to create an "OOO appointment," the user could specify the date and time as usual, and the recipients of the appointment. Then I would like to automatically create and send the two appointments described above.
Is this possible? If so, can someone help me with getting started on this? There is a lot of documentation around add-ins but it's hard to get started with very little email programming experience.
I have looked at some tutorials on creating Outlook add-ins, and I'm not sure if this is in the purview of add-ins. There are plenty of similar questions, but none seem to involve sending multiple appointments.
